# Understanding setTimeout() and callbacks with jQuery Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Trying to get my head around method ordering, setTimeout() and callbacks.

I need to call the [Isotope method layout()](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout) once a setTimeout() function is complete, otherwise the layout is off and elements overlap.

```
// <--- CODE

this.timeout = 400;

this.update = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".item.is-loading").each(function(index) {
            var _time = 100 * index,
                $this = $(this);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $this.removeClass("is-loading").find("img").css({
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "auto"
                });
            }, _time);
        })
    }, instance.timeout);

    instance.feed.isotope("layout");
};

// ---> CODE
```

I can see that layout() is being called before as setTimoute() is complete is it's asynchronous, but I can't figure out a nice way to solve the issue without using another setTimeout??

Comment: FYI - `$this` is already a jQuery object, so `$($this)` isn't needed.

Comment: so,  you want that final call to `.isotope("layout")` to be deferred until all the inner timeouts have finished, and those themselves don't start until 400ms after the `update` function is called?

Comment: Why not just put the `instance.feed.isotope("layout");` before the end (and after the existing code) of the function executed by timeout?

Comment: @Alnitak yes please. This is the only way I can fix the layout. It appears to down to the fluid design and the images...I tried the imagesLoaded plugin with no success

Comment: and the timeouts are necessary for visual effect? (i.e. you're intentionally animating each `.is_loading` element in turn) ?

Comment: @Alnitak yes, purely visual

Comment: @Prusse I think I've tried that... tired multiple location, still have the same issue

Comment: imageloaded.js should work. If your using isotope v2, you need to load it as a separate js file since it is not included as it is in v1.56. What was your code for imagesloaded.js? A fiddle would help understand your issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this (no pun intended!) with jQuery promises:

```
this.update = function() {

    // immediately create an array of deferred objects, one for
    // each element in the list below
    var defs = $(".item.is-loading").map(function() {
        return $.Deferred();
    }).get();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".item.is-loading").each(function(index) {
            var _time = 100 * index,
                $this = $(this);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $this.removeClass("is-loading").find("img").css({
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "auto"
                });
                defs[index].resolve();   // flag that this deferred task finished
            }, _time);
        })
    }, instance.timeout);

    // once they're all done, update the layout
    return $.when.apply($, defs).then(function() {
        instance.feed.isotope("layout");
    });
};
```

The `defs` array has to be created immediately otherwise the `$.when` call further down will have nothing to work on.

As each inner `setTimeout` call completes the respective entry in `defs` is "resolved", and the `$.when()` call ensures that only when they're *all* resolved will the layout get updated.

Furthermore, the `update` function itself now also returns a promise, so that you can synchronise other events on the completion of the entire async task.

Comment: like magic.... now to read up on Deferred objects.  Do you find you use them a lot? New to me

Comment: I use them a huge amount.  These days It's probably worth learning the new ES6 promises as well - I've used jQuery promises here since you're already using jQuery and thus avoids the overhead of another library.

Comment: Many thanks! A solution is more worthwhile when you come across something new! I bookmarked this (https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) a while back...maybe time to experiment